# How do I do a glow effect as shown in this tutorial but in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, effects

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyGViC-PELo

How do I get emission nodes to create glowing eyes like he does in Cycles, but in Internal?

Answer (score 2):

The glow effect in that tutorial is made using the compositor, not the render engine itself.
The compositor works the same way for every rendering engine so the techniques described there should work both for Cycles and Blender Internal.

Just add a *Glare* node with fog glow and it should work identically.

As for the material itself you can use the *Properties Window > Materials > Shading > Emit* option or alternatively activate the *Shadeless* checkbox right beside it.

Adjust the emission intensity as desired.