# How to create haze around a uv sphere with emission shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, world

So, I have this lit up ball on a black background.

[image: The LitUp Ball]

The background needs to be black, and i would like a sort of haze around the ball. Other questions did not solve my problem. I was thinking something with a volume scatter node, but i tried it and it doesn't work with a black background.

Here's the world setup:
[image: World setup]

So, yeah. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120563/how-do-i-make-a-luminescent-gas-cloud

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56198/how-do-i-do-a-glow-effect-as-shown-in-this-tutorial-but-in-blender-internal/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89653/how-to-make-small-objects-emit-a-ton-of-light/

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. I will research more before posting next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of effects are often demanded to the compositing, using glare node and/or gaussian blur nodes.

[image]